# value comaprison separated by commas in database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database and there is column which contains multiple questions separated by commas(hockey,cooking,movies).

My question is that right now I'm firing a select query which is like this:-

```
$query="$sql="SELECT * from user where hobbies='$form_id'";
```

Actually in `$form_id` I'm passing the value say(games), now I want to display all the rows in the database which contains 'games'in them. Remember i have to compare this value with multiple values in the columns in that particulars of the database.

I'm using corephp with mysql as database. I really don't know how to do this please help me out.

Comment: This is why normalizing your data is important. An easy task just became a lot more difficult.

Comment: You either have to combine several comparisions via OR clauses, or you need to setup a search index beforehand, if you need acceptable performance.

Comment: You're looking at a one-to-many relationship, so you need a second table with two columns `user_id` and `hobby` and a single row per hobby. Maybe you even want a many-to-many relationship if you don't want to duplicate hobbies globally. That's how RDBMSs are supposed to be used.

Comment: This is the reason why `link tables` exist. [link](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_linking_table.php)

Comment: A better design is to have a `users` table, a `hobbies` table and a `user_hobbies` table. Your `user_hobbies` table links the users to their hobbies (each hobby would be one row, and the primary key would probably be `(user,hobby)`). It seems more complicated, but believe me it will save you lots of time in the long run. With your current design, how would you remove a single hobby from a user without having to write code to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE hobbies LIKE '%$form_id%';
```

but you should change your database schema like:

```
users(id, name, firstname, ...)
hobbies(id, name)
user_hobbies(id_user, id_hobby)
```

Comment: Note that mysql doesn't support ILIKE()
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Robin can you please tell me whatis the difference between LIKE and IN condition in select by using this example. It want to display the same results using IN in select query. I have used this query but not getting any output($sql="SELECT * from user where hobbies IN('$form_id')" ;)...if you have anyidea pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

In reaction to John Conde's remark, the problem here is lying to your data model.
If a person can have several hobbies, you shouldn't store those hobbies in a field of the "person" table. Long story short, you should have 3 tables :

1. "Person" Table => Everything related to the person, and unique : name, birthdate, etc... NO HOBBIES !
2. "Hobbies" table => Everything related to the hobbies. The most simple form would be 2 fields : `id` & `hobbyname`. You could imagine adding more details in other fields, like is it an indoor or outdoor hobby, etc...
3. "PersonHobbies" table, used to link both : In that one, you'll probably have only 2 fields, 1 for the person id, one for the hobby id. Then if a person has 3 hobbies, you just write 3 records to that table with the same user id and a different hobby id

There are many advantages to this normalization. the biggest one is that it makes your queries easier to select but also update hobbies of a user. It also makes it easier to count how many hobbies each person has and so on. so, you SHOULD ALWAYS normalize your data, it doesn't take much more time when creating database and waves you a lot of time afterwards